Trying to substitute an element of a given type by an integer
I have two lists:
a = {{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 16, 12}, {13, 7, 11}, {14}}
b = {0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}

The a list contains the positions of terms in b. So I apply the function to find those terms:
b[[#]] & /@ a

which yields
{{List}, {List, List, List}, {List, List, List, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0}}

I want to substitute every List term by a 0. This is what I have tried, but it fails:
b[[#]] & /@ a /. _Symbol -> 0

because it counts the lists themselves, not just the List terms.
0[0[0], 0[0, 0, 0], 0[0, 0, 0, 0, 2], 0[2, 0, 2], 0[0]]

Is there any way to do this properly? Can I apply b[[#]] & /@ a so that it takes b[[0]]==0?

a = {{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 16, 12}, {13, 7, 11}, {14}};
b = {0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
   1, 0};

Replace[b[[#]] & /@ a, List -> 0, All]


{{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0}}

But I would not do it this way. Instead I would prepend 0 to b and add 1 to each number in a, thus avoiding any replacement.
a = {{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 16, 12}, {13, 7, 11}, {14}};
b = {0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
   1, 0};

a = a + 1;
b = Prepend[b, 0];

b[[#]] & /@ a


{{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0}}

Or the same way without modifying a or b.
a = {{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 16, 12}, {13, 7, 11}, {14}};
b = {0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
   1, 0};

Prepend[b, 0][[#]] & /@ (a + 1)


{{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0}}


That's a smart method, thanks

Using ReplaceAll:
a = {{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 16, 12}, {13, 7, 11}, {14}};
b = {0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
   1, 0};

a /. a_ /; a \[Element] PositiveIntegers :> b[[a]]

Using Lookup:
lut = MapIndexed[First@#2 -> #1 &, b]

Lookup[lut, #, 0] & /@ a



{{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0}}


Here are a couple of alternatives:
Do the replacement as part of the mapped function:
Map[b[[#]] /. List -> 0 &, a, {-1}]

Change the head of the expression you're Parting into to match what you want:
Map[(0 @@ b)[[#]] &, a, {-1}]


a = {{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 16, 12}, {13, 7, 11}, {14}};

b = {0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};


An alternative using Map and If:
b[[If[FreeQ[#, 0], #, # + 1]]] & /@ a


{{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0}}


Extract[b, List /@ a, Replace[#, List -> 0, {1}] &]

(* {{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0}} *)

Or
MapAt[0 &, b[[#]] & /@ a, Position[a, 0]]

(* {{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {0}} *)


This is what you get??? Does not seem to be correct.
